# Can i have JSON Configuration for SF Stateless Service and Override a value for a specific instance of it?

Tags: json, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have an SF application which has a stateless service. The Stateless service is currently having its Configuration defined in JSON format.I would like to host 2 instances of that application and each having different value for a key in this json configuration ?. I know it is possible for configurations in Settings.xml by specifying overrides while creating Application instance, but is their a way i can achieve something similar for JSON Configurations. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, config overrides only work with Settings.xml.

Even then, config overrides flow down from *application parameters*, which means you can only set overrides per *application*, not per service within an application.

Services can be given an arbitrary byte array called "initialization data" during [creation time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt124028.aspx). But this does not flow down into configuration files, and it cannot be changed or updated or upgraded later - you only get to set initialization data for a service **once**.

Comment: Thanks @Vaclav Understood. So i guess will have to look at other alternatives for Controlling configurations which change per service instance..